# Meta tag and open graph protocol issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html, seo, facebook-opengraph

I used the open graph on my pages, but unfortunately it does not work and I do not understand why .

Mvc Code:

```
@section MetaTags
{
    <meta name="keywords" content="@Model.GoogleKeywords" >
    <meta name="description" content="@Model.GoogleDesc" >
    <meta property="og:type" content="product" >
    <meta property="og:image" content="@Model.MainImageUrl?w=200" >
    <meta property="og:title" content="@Model.Name" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="@Model.GoogleDesc" >
    <meta property="og:url" content="@(Request.Url.Scheme)://store.com/products/@Model.Url.ToLower()" >
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="SiteName" >
}
```

Output:

```
<meta name="keywords" content="Machin , Store" >
<meta name="description" content="Machin" >
<meta property="og:type" content="product" >
<meta property="og:image" content="http://store.com/ProductImages/Images_f93cc5d0-70ff-444f-bcdc-0415b8b6a2f3/TWD25-min - Copy (2).jpg?w=200" >
<meta property="og:title" content="Machin Tit" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Machin" >
<meta property="og:url" content="http://store.com/products/e7673dbc-b375-4de4-abe0-8fd985e6697f" >
<meta property="og:site_name" content="SiteName" >
```

Where did i make a mistake?

Thanks.

Comment: What is it exactly that doesn’t work?

Comment: You shouldn't have any spaces in the image URL in the og:image property at first glance.

Comment: @Jon Ryan ... That is when placing the page link in places like the telegram ،Photos and page view do not appear

Comment: @ Jason Roner ......  I was wondering if the problem was not there

Comment: I was hoping you were going to say it was just the image not showing in which case like @JasonRoner I was going to point out the spaces in the images url. I can’t see anything else immediately obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/

It should tell you exactly what the problem is (in theory)